# Grabbing the contents of multiple curl handles from a curl multi exec?

Tags: php, curl

So, basically I need to get the contents of around 100-200 webpages. I'd like to use curl_multi_* so that I can grab it all at once, but I'm not sure if that's even possible.

I know with curl, you'd just set the returntransfer option to true and output the execution, but how would I do this with curl_multi_*?

If impossible, is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

I stumbled upon this while trying to do the same thing myself.  I figured I'd add my solution to help anybody who has the same problem in the future.  First, I'll assume you have an array of your curl handlers as such:

```
$mh = curl_multi_init();
$requests = array();
foreach ($someArray as $identifier => $url) {
    $requests[$identifier] = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($requests[$identifier], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    //any other options you need to set go here
    curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $requests[$identifier]);
}
```

I also assume you ran the requests:

```
do {
    $status = curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
} while ($status === CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM || $running);
```

Finally, we get to the answer to your question:

```
$returned = array();
foreach ($requests as $identifier => $request) {
    $returned[$identifier] = curl_multi_getcontent($request);
    curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $request); //assuming we're being responsible about our resource management
    curl_close($request); //being responsible again.  THIS MUST GO AFTER curl_multi_getcontent();
}
```

`$returned` now contains all your data.

Answer (score -1):

It is an easy work to do with curl multi interface.

curl_multi interface provide kind of grouping function.

You initiate a normal curl operation with easy interface, register to multi handle, perform multiple job at once, that's all.

If you work in PHP, take a look at [This](http://www.askapache.com/php/curl-multi-downloads.html) page (googled with 'curl multiple').

Comment: That really doesn't help at all.